# Помогите выполнить задание

Tags: java, алгоритм

Помогите пожалуйста выполнить это задание

> Задание 5, вариант 4.
>
> Разработать и промоделировать алгоритм выполнения
>   заданной операции над двоичным вектором А. Представить
>   соответствующий фрагмент java-программы.
>
> Количество байтов в двоичном векторе: 2
>
> Поменять местами третью и четвёртую тетрады

Comment: Покажите тот код который вы уже написали и расскажите что в нём у вас не работает. Просто так домашку тут по фотам не делают. Вам надо показать что вы хоть что-то попытались самостоятельно сделать. Далее мы вам поможем

Comment: Гоша, хорошо что вы переписали задачу вместо фото. Но это не меняет сути проблемы. Пожалуйста, решайте учебные задания самостоятельно. )

Answer (score 1):

Поизвращаемся, пожалуй: http://ideone.com/4rgeEt.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        short x = (short)0xABCD;
        short y = (short)Integer.parseInt(String.format("%04x", x).replaceAll("(.)(.)(..$)", "$2$1$3"), 16);
        System.out.println(String.format("%04x", y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаю ты сломаешь ему мозг ...

Comment: @elik, а как же ещё)))